# Maintaining tables based on column value of other tables

Tags: sql

I got a situation like I need to create tables based on column value of Parent table.Here is the scenario

I have dynamic Input table where the users can define the control they want to have them in pages.Right now the table is all the properties for each control.For example if I want to enable the user to Add TextBox and Checkbox the table will have the fields like

**Common Fields**

- InputID
- InputName
- Type ( textbox/Checkbox)
- Label

**TextBox spec. fields**

- Text
- MultiLine
- MaxLength
- IsNumbersOnly

**CheckBox Spec. Fields**

- IsDefaultChecked
- CheckBoxText
- GroupID - If I want to have multiple check boxes in a group

The above one is just for sample. Like this I would like to have many controls dropdown,listbox etc. Am bit confused to redefine the tables for maintaining this information. One option is to define the tables as follow

**InputTable**

- InputID
- InputName
- Type ( textbox/Checkbox)
- Label

**TextBoxTable**

- InputID
- And all the textbox related fields

**CheckBoxTable**

- InputID
- And all the checkbox related fields

and so on..

Is this a better approach to maintain values in table based on column value of other table (In this case InputTable). Or is there any better approach to do the same.

Please let me know if you have any better ideas..

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a generic table for all the controls with an id, the name... an then a table with the id referenced by a foreign key, plus two columns : property_name and value. You populate this table with each property of each control.